# How to create singleton for each thread in Cocoa?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, singleton

is there any common pattern to create singleton objects for each thread?

When I send a `sharedInstance` message to the singleton class, I expect an instance that is shared only for the `currentThread`.

Thanks

EDIT: I found this post very useful http://ddeville.me/2011/02/creating-shared-instances-of-non-thread-safe-classes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A singleton and one object per thread requirement is an contradiction.
You probably want a `thread local` object. That is one object specific for each thread.

Thread  local objects can be implemented by using `[NSThread threadDictionary].`
There you could store such an object as `NSValue` which can hold even a pointer.